# Uso del género gramatical para desambiguar a qué sustantivo o frase nominal modifica un adjetivo

Tags: gramática

En mi tesis, escribí la siguiente oración:

> Trabajaremos con las imágenes bajo `f^*` de ciertos generadores del anillo `X`, llamadas las clases de Chern de `E` y denotadas `c_i(E)`.

(El significado de esta oración es irrelevante para mi pregunta.)

Mi intención es que el uso de las formas femeninas de los adjetivos “llamadas” y “denotadas” haga claro, por concordancia de género gramatical, que “las clases de Chern de `E`” son “las imágenes bajo `f^*` de...” y no “ciertos generadores del anillo `X`”. ¿Pero es esto en verdad suficientemente claro?

También podría haber escrito lo siguiente:

> Trabajaremos con las imágenes bajo `f^*` de ciertos generadores del anillo `X`. Estas imágenes son llamadas las clases de Chern de `E` y se denotan por `c_i(E)`.

Sin embargo, mi tesis ya está sobrecargada de usos del verbo copulativo “ser”. Cada oportunidad de eliminar un uso de este verbo es preciosa.

Comment: Yo entendí claramente el primer párrafo antes de leer la explicación, aunque me sobra el artículo "las" antes de clases. No sé si es por terminología.

Comment: @Danielillo: No, tienes razón. La palabra “las” antes de “clases” está de más. Cuando escribo sobre matemática, pienso demasiado en inglés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la frase está bien construida, lo que lleva a confusión es la repetición de participios "sinónimos" en la segunda parte: llamadas/denotadas.

Limpiaría la frase e intentaría dar mayor identidad o diferenciación a estos dos elementos para una mejor comprensión y profesionalidad:

> Trabajaremos con las imágenes bajo `f^*` de ciertos generadores del anillo `X`, llamadas clases de Chern de `E`; nomenclatura `c_i(E)`.

Answer (score 0):

Algunas ideas, sírvase combinar o remodelar aquello que considere que no proceda o simplemente no le gusta;

> Trabajaremos con las imágenes bajo f^* de ciertos generadores del
> anillo X, llamadas las clases de Chern de E y denotadas c_i(E).

- Trabajaremos con imágenes bajo f^* con ciertos generadores del anillo X, llamadas clases de Chern de E y expresadas como c_i(E).
- Nos desenvolveremos a partir de imágenes bajo f^* con ciertos generadores del anillo X, llamadas clases de Chern de E, y expresadas como c_i(E).
- Nos desarrollaremos a partir de imágenes bajo f^* de ciertos generadores del anillo X, llamadas "las clases de Chern de E" y simbolizadas como c_i(E).

---

> Trabajaremos con las imágenes bajo f^* de ciertos generadores del
> anillo X. Estas imágenes son llamadas las clases de Chern de E y se
> denotan por c_i(E).

- Las imágenes con las que trabajaremos bajo f^* con ciertos generadores del anillo X, son conocidas como las clases de Chern de E y se expresan como c_i(E).
- Las imágenes con las que trabajaremos bajo f^* de ciertos generadores del anillo X, denominadas clases de Chern de E, representadas de la manera c_i(E).

Comment: Estoy completamente seguro de que, en la oración original, la palabra “llamadas” es la forma femenina plural del adjetivo “llamado”. Como sustantivo, “llamada” sería, por ejemplo, una llamada de teléfono.

Comment: Llevas razón y pido perdón, "llamadas" también aparece como adj. Forma del femenino plural de llamado, participio de llamar o de llamarse. " Y "denotada — adj. Forma del femenino de denotado, participio de denotar. "se denotan" V. forma denotar, denotarse.

Comment: No es necesario pedir disculpas. No es que me hayas ofendido. Esto sólo es un intercambio de información en Internet.